# Get the visible elements in a jquery.jcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility, jcarousel, carousel

I'm building a JavaScript carousel and I need to extract the URL's of the links shown on every change of the carousel.

I'm using jQuery jCarousel as it allows the developer to bind different handlers to change events.

The carousel should display 4 items at a time and scroll 4 items at a time.

The itemFirstInCallback handler I've implemented gets the href of the first link in a page (e.g. index 1, index 5)

I need to get the currently displayed URL's for the first link displayed in all 4 visible

elements and im wondering how to achieve this?

demo code below...

**Setup Carousel**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#featured_carousel_list').jcarousel({ 
visible: 4, 
scroll: 4, 
initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback, 
buttonNextHTML: null, 
buttonPrevHTML: null,
itemFirstInCallback: function (carousel, liElement, intemIndex, action) {
                    // get URL's of visible items
                    var item_URL = $(liElement).children('a:last-child').attr('href');
                    alert(item_URL);
                }

            });


        });

        function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
            $('#next_button').bind('click', function () { carousel.next(); return false;});
            $('#prev_button').bind('click', function () { carousel.prev(); return false;});
        }
```

**HTML List**

```
<div id="prev_button"><<</div>
<div id="next_button">>></div>
    <ul class="featured_carousel_list" id="featured_carousel_list">
        <li><img src="images/item_sample_image.gif" alt="" width="180" height="90" /><a href="display.aspx?tid=1" class="item_text_link">title</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/item_sample_image.gif" alt="" width="180" height="90" /><a href="display.aspx?tid=2" class="item_text_link">title</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/item_sample_image.gif" alt="" width="180" height="90" /><a href="display.aspx?tid=3" class="item_text_link">title</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/item_sample_image.gif" alt="" width="180" height="90" /><a href="display.aspx?tid=4" class="item_text_link">title</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/item_sample_image.gif" alt="" width="180" height="90" /><a href="display.aspx?tid=5" class="item_text_link">title</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/item_sample_image.gif" alt="" width="180" height="90" /><a href="display.aspx?tid=6" class="item_text_link">title</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/item_sample_image.gif" alt="" width="180" height="90" /><a href="display.aspx?tid=7" class="item_text_link">title</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/item_sample_image.gif" alt="" width="180" height="90" /><a href="display.aspx?tid=8" class="item_text_link">title</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to get the URLs of all the visible elements. You can achieve this by replacing your `itemFirstInCallback` callback with a `itemVisibleInCallback`:

```
itemVisibleInCallback: function(carousel, liElement) {
  var item_URL = $(liElement).children('a:last-child').attr('href');
  console.log(item_URL);
}
```

This callback will be triggered for all 4 items as they turn visible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actualy needed to get all the URL's in the same callback and report them back to a server via one ajax call so the 4 diffrent callbacks wasnt realy an option. I ended up iterating through the next 3 <li> elements by using the slice function...



`itemFirstInCallback: function (carousel, liElement, itemIndex, action) {
var urlItems = [];
                    $.each($(liElement).parent().children().slice((itemIndex - 1), (itemIndex + num_items) - 1), function (index, value) {
 var itemURL = $(value).children('a:last-child').attr('href');
 urlItems.push(itemURL);
 });`